# Difference between .../thermal_zone0/temp and .../thermal_zone0/subsystem/thermal_zone0/temp?

Tags: sensor, filesystem, temperature

To read the temperature in Raspbian (and most other systems) you can read the file `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`, which will output the temperature in millicelsius, like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi0 ~ $ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp 
54072
```

There is also a file, `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/subsystem/thermal_zone0/temp` which works exactly the same way, and outputs the exact same numbers.

So my question is: Why the different location? What meaning does the extra directory `/subsystem/` have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2016-02-19 22:24 thermal_zone0 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2016-02-25 17:31 /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/subsystem/thermal_zone0 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0
```

Comment: I know that they're the same sensor. I just don't know why there would be two files for the output.

Comment: They are just links to the same place. This is usually for compatibility with other distributions or previous usage.